# Trace time spent on each app in Android?

Tags: android, service, background-process

Is it possible to run a background service in android which can store the time spent on any application in android and also if we can take timely screenshots with the use of that background service in android.
I mean here that we can know that user has spent this much amount of time on this app and also take screenshots after each 5-15 mins?

Is it possible?

Please suggest some solution here.

**Edited
Ok Lets forget screenshots. How can we trace time spent on which application? Same as below app**
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appuccino.frequencyfree

Comment: Really interesting question -- specially on facebook : jock,

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appuccino.frequencyfree

Comment: "and also take screenshots" -- fortunately, no, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons. The exception is on rooted devices.

Comment: you can get running processes and monitor working time of each process in the system. what about screenshots - you have to be rooted, and than you can take screenshots from background service.

Answer (score 0):

You can get running  processes by calling.

```
ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()
```

you can save an array or List and get the processes running in foreground one by one. Then for getting ElapsedTime you can call  `getElapsedCpuTime()`